# How to do a named export of an overloaded function in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, export, overloading

**pickCard.ts**

This is the example from:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

```
function pickCard(x: { suit: string; card: number }[]): number;
function pickCard(x: number): { suit: string; card: number };
function pickCard(x: any): any {
  // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
  // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
  if (typeof x == "object") {
    let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
    return pickedCard;
  }
  // Otherwise just let them pick the card
  else if (typeof x == "number") {
    let pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13);
    return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 };
  }
}

export pickCard; // DOES NOT WORK
```

I can't use a function expression like: `export const pickCard = () => {};` because overloads won't work on function expressions.

**QUESTION**

How can I do a named export on the `pickCard` function. Note: the name should be `pickCard`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
export function pickCard(x: { suit: string; card: number }[]): number;
export function pickCard(x: number): { suit: string; card: number };
export function pickCard(x: any): any {
  // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
  // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
  if (typeof x == "object") {
    let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
    return pickedCard;
  }
  // Otherwise just let them pick the card
  else if (typeof x == "number") {
    let pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13); 
    return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 };
  }
}
```

Use in other file:

```
import { pickCard } from ".";

pickCard([{ suit: 'test', card: 10 }]);
pickCard(21);
```